# Saving data into SQL using PHP (C#)

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on program (written in C#) that would run on few computers at once (their amount will very likely change over time). I want to save some data into SQL everytime some event occurs (nothing too complex, just a bit of information).

I'm not really sure how to do this the best way. I have these two options, I can connect directly to the SQL database straight from the program and insert everything I need, but I find this rather unsafe because someone could you this in bad way and gain access to my SQL without my permissions.

So I came up with this idea, I will have certain PHP file on the server which will handle all the data (my program will open internal hidden web browser window with address of the PHP file and all needed variables (I will use GET over here) and then it will close and wait for another event to happen).

Is the second solution way too bad habit to do or is it reasonably okay? Or even better, is there any better, more clean, solution to this kind of problem?

(It's not any kind of spyware or anything like that, it's just doing kind of diagnostics on the computer and giving me results with user's knowledge..)

Each time any event occurs, I have to insert one line into the table and it includes computer's ID, time and the event information.

The address used could look somewhat like this `http:\\server.com\handle.php?id=xxxxxxxx&time=xx-xx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxx&data=something`

Comment: If you don't have to use PHP, you can try asmx web service(in the server)

Comment: @jackjop Could you please explain this a little bit more or provide me some link? I'm not really sure whether I'm able to do that..

Comment: I would write a web service using ASP.NET.  Web API in particular can be accessed easily via c# code and fits the current RESTful paradigm.

Comment: Your problem has two components: how does the user contact the data endpoint and how is the endpoint secured? SQL Server has permissions and you can use AD accounts. Likewise the program will only work when the user is connected to the corporate network and SQL Server is available unless you specifically code some background data synchronization logic.

Comment: well just think it as an .exe file which works in the server(which has the database). You can fill the web service with methods to do sql insert... here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359

Comment: if you don't want a web service just encrpt the query string and do a get method and decrypt it again and check if it has the same as your type like "www.example.com/handle.php?whsadxx1123asdasdasdazmdjdj"

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running on a LAN or are you on the Internet?

If you can access your SQL Server directly from your application on the default SQL Port (1433) what kind of security issues do you see?

If you run your application in a certain security context, you can connect to your SQL server using Windows security -> no username and password is sent.

BR
Frank

Comment: My application is running on user's computer and each computer can be on a different Internet connection so they aren't connected to the SQL server through LAN. The security risk is that someone might be able to decompile the program and see the database login query and then they could possible steal someone's data from my database, right?

Comment: In that case you need a different approach. I would setup a RESTfull webservice that connects to your SQL Server. Your client then talks to your webservice on port 80 (maybe even https -> secure).

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to submit form straight from C# code somehow? It would be a lot easier for me to do and it would work a lot more simple and more likely without any further problems.. I couldn't really find anything, do you have any idea? (I want to just send those variables using POST instead of GET in this case)

Comment: 1) If you are able to make a complete secure C# program, non-hackable, how would you from your C# program talk to your SQL Server via the internet? (port?)

Comment: 2) I would suggest to read up on how you can make the communication work. Look how mobile-apps works. Often the mobile app talks to a backend layer hosted on a webserver using a RESTFull interface (OData).